# Canonical choice of many elements not contained in a set

Tags: set-theory, axiom-of-choice

It often happens that we want to adjoin a 'new' element $\infty$ to a set $X$, e.g. when constructing the [Alexandroff compactification](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Definition:Alexandroff_Extension), or adding "infinity" to the real numbers or any ordered set. This is not a problem, because there is no set that contains all sets, or because by the [axiom of foundation](https://proofwiki.org/wiki/Axiom:Axiom_of_Foundation) we can take any element of some nonempty subset of $X$ (or $X$ itself should $X$ only contain the empty set).

It becomes tricky when we want to do this for many sets at once; e.g. when defining a functor: we have to choose an element for each set, and choice is scary. I figured that we can take $\infty=\{X\}\cup\bigcup X$: if $X$ is a singleton $\{a\}$ then $a\neq X$ by foundation. If $X$ is not, $\infty$ strictly contains its elements.

Then I started wondering if:

> For a fixed set $I$, does there exist a canonical choice of $I$ distinct elements (i.e. an injective map with domain $I$) not in $X$, for all sets $X$?

If $I=\{1,\ldots,n\}$ is finite and well-ordered we can iterate the construction of $\infty$ above.

My first idea was to take something like $\infty \cup\{i\}$ for each $i\in I$, but we may not be able to distinguish those when $i=X$ or when $i$ is an element of $X$ or of a subset of $X$. The problem lies in those sets $X$ that are related to $I$ through its elements or their elements or .. etc.

Comment: Doesn't $\infty = \{X\}$ work?

Comment: @immibis Yes; I only learned that a set cannot contain itself after posting this.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Even Foundation is not necessary.

One can easily prove that for every set $X$, there is some $Y\subseteq X$ such that there is no element of $X$ of the form $(Y,x)$, for any $x$. (This involves a standard Russell-like proof.) Moreover, this $Y$ is canonically defined for $X$, once we fix a definition for $(Y,x)$, so for example, the Kuratowski pairing would give us a canonical $Y$.

Now given $I$, simply pick this $Y$ and consider $\{Y\}\times I$. This set will be disjoint from $X$ and clearly have size $I$.

Comment: I see why there is such a $Y$. But why is there a canonical definition for some such?

Comment: @Stefan: You can define it explicitly by diagonalizing the map $X\to\mathcal P(X)$ that takes $x\in X$ to its first component if it's an ordered pair and the first component is a subset of $X$, and $\varnothing$ otherwise.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Yeah, that works. Thanks.

Comment: @HenningMakholm What do you mean by diagonalizing? If I take the _diagonal_ of that map, assuming Foundation I get the $x\in X$ with $x=(x,x')$, of which there are none, so $Y=\varnothing$, but this doesn't work.

Comment: @barto: Cantor's theorem tells us that this map $X\to \mathcal P(X)$ cannot be surjective, and the well-known _diagonal proof_ of the theorem shows how to explicitly construct an element of $\mathcal P(X)$ that is not in the range of the the map. Expanding the proof (and optimizing a few unnecessary details away) we get something like $$Y = \{x\in X\mid x\text{ is NOT an ordered pair }(a,b)\text{ with }x\in a\}$$ If Foundation holds, this is the same as $Y=X$, but the definition will also work in an ill-founded universe (where we may need to exclude some $x$s).

Answer (score 4):

Yes, this is possible -- even in the absence of choice. Simply let
$$
\pi \colon I \to X^C, i \mapsto (i, X).
$$
The $\in$-rank of $(i,X)$ is strictly larger than that of $X$ -- and hence that of any element of $X$ -- which ensures that $(i,X) \not \in X$ for any $i \in I$.

Comment: Since you mentioned foundation in your question let me emphasize that this, too, uses foundation in order for the $\in$-rank to be defined globally.

Comment: Ehm the question is for all $X$ and fixed $I$. Perhaps that wasn't clear, or I don't understand the answer.

Comment: @barto I've updated my answer.

Comment: @barto: In principle, if you're only fixing $I$ and asking about *all* $X$, then you're appealing to global choice, not just choice.

Comment: @Asaf I'm not sure what you are saying. Let's call $\pi$ as above $\pi_{I,X}$. Then $\{ (I,X, \pi_{I,X}) \mid I,X \text{ are sets} \}$ is a definable class in $\mathrm{ZF}$. How does global choice come into play?

Comment: @Stefan: Of course. But in principle, when you asking how to choose for *all* sets, you're asking about global choice.

Comment: @StefanMesken By curiosity, what is the definition of $X^C$ at second line of your answer?

Comment: It's the complement of $X^C$ (which, of course, is a definable, proper class). Note that $\pi$, however, is a set. $\pi = \{ (i,(i,X)) \mid i \in I \}$ -- the usage of the proper class $X^C$ only serves to emphasize that the range of $\pi$ is disjoint from $X$.